How to get the frequency of items (All text) from a collection variable in salesforce flow?
I am trying to get the frequency of each item in a collection variable.
The collection variable contains all the text values from a field on the contact for different records. Out of all the values I would like to know which text value occurred the most number of times.
I have tried the following:

I looped through the collection variable and adding a decision
element to check if this current value exists in a separate
collection.

If it does not exist I will add this value to that new collection
along with the count as 1 next to it (Formula)

If it exists I would like to increment its counter by 1. However, I
am not able to increment the value as it is of type Text


.
Any ideas here would be appreciated.

Easier approach: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/create-reports-and-dashboards-for-sales-and-marketing-managers/group-and-categorize-your-data
